# Provide same value to outer and inner control using ControlValueAccessor with ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a directive to perform DecimalPipe into a input value without changing control, or better, I give a change in control without changing input value.

Expected result is: DecimalPipe to input value (like string) AND parsed float to FormControl value, and its ok, just not being inherited..

I use a component to give functions to addValue by step, and acess this component by ControlValueAccessor. However, the value printed by the "inner" and "outer" form is different.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enbqmf

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why `emitEvent` and `emitModelToViewChange` is being set false?
Without them, you are good to go.

File: _directives/input-decimal.directive.ts

```js
this.control.control.setValue(val, {
   emitEvent: false,
   emitModelToViewChange: false
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot specify this. My expected result is: DecimalPipe to input value (like string) AND parsed float to FormControl value. This is the reason why i set parsedFloat to FormControl with emitEvent set to false.